# Form input not passing to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple form in my rails app with a few inputs.

They all submit fine, except for this one:

```
  <%= f.input :trip_price, as: :string %>
```

No error is thrown, the form just submits and the value of this in the db is nil.

Here is the relevant bit of schema.rb

```
 create_table "routes", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.string   "operator"
 t.string   "startPoint"
 t.string   "endPoint"
 t.string   "description"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.integer  "trip_price"
 end
```

I'm using simple_form if that is relevant. Maybe it has something to do with being an integer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check your server/web console to see if there are any errors throw? ex. what is the response of the POST request sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I had to add :trip_price to my permitted params. D'oh!

Comment: Was just about to answer that :)